# Erro ao substituir ocorrência numa string utilizando replaceAll

Tags: java, string, regex

Faço a extração do texto de várias linhas de um PDF, no início de cada linha possuo uma configuração do tamanho e família da fonte utilizada naquela linha, mas em seguida preciso remover essas informações.

Primeiramente fiz usando `replace`, da seguinte forma:

```
String myText = line.replace(fontConfiguration, "");
```

E este exemplo de *strings*:

```
String line = "[ABCDEE+Georgia,BoldItalic-9.0]Relação de poemas";
String fontConfiguration = "[ABCDEE+Georgia,BoldItalic-9.0]";
```

Eu consigo substituir perfeitamente, porém ainda há ocorrências de *fontConfiguration* no texto, então coloquei *replaceAll*.

**Minha dúvida é**: Por que eu obtenho essa *exception* quando utilizo o *replaceAll*?

Este é um exemplo que apresentará erro:

```
String line = "[ABCDEE+Calibri-11.04]1 ";
String fontConfiguration = "[ABCDEE+Calibri-11.04]";
String myText = line.replaceAll(fontConfiguration, "");
```

*Exception*:

> Method threw 'java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException' exception.
>   java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal character range near
>   index 16 [ABCDEE+Calibri-11.04]
>                 ^

Comment: Achei que o replaceAll pegava uma sequência de caracteres como o replace, nunca parei para pensar que em casos como: `String newStr = str.replaceAll("This", "That");` também é uma regEx. Obrigada a todos.

Comment: Por qual motivo estão desqualificando essa pergunta? nosso amigo precisa de ajuda com expressões regulares.!

Comment: @DanielaMorais o problema e que o `replaceAll()` diferente do `replace()` utiliza expressões regulares, logo sua string deveria ficar `"\\[ABCDEE\\+Georgia,BoldItalic-9.0\\]"`

Comment: @DavidSchrammel os dois usam expressões regulares, só que o `replace` usa *literal pattern*. Se a pergunta for aberta (foi fechada sabe-se lá por que) tento incluir uma resposta considerando este comportamento diferente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tanto [replace(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-) quanto [replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) fazem substituição usando *matching* de padrões usando expressões regulares. A questão que fica é: sendo que tanto [replace(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-) quanto [replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) usam expressões regulares, por que apenas [replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) dá erro para a mesma entrada? Observe a forma com que tais métodos fazem isto:

- [replace(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-)

```java
public String replace(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement) {
    return Pattern.compile(target.toString(), Pattern.LITERAL).matcher(this)
            .replaceAll(Matcher.quoteReplacement(replacement.toString()));
}
```

- [replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-)

```java
public String replaceAll(String regex, String replacement) {
    return Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(this).replaceAll(replacement);
}
```

A diferença, como pode ser vista pelo códito deles, é a forma com que o [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) é criando. Enquanto [replace(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-) usa `Pattern.LITERAL`, ou seja, a grosso modo a entrada é tratada como caracteres normal e não uma expressão regular. Por exemplo, se [replace(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-) fosse assim:

```java
public String replace(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement) {
    return Pattern.compile(target.toString()).matcher(this)
            .replaceAll(Matcher.quoteReplacement(replacement.toString()));
}
```

Também teríamos problemas com a entrada `[ABCDEE+Calibri-11.04]` como *regex*, pois ela não é uma expressão regular válida e agora estamos não usando uma sequência literal de caracteres, mas sim um padrão normal de expressão regular.

Vale lembrar que não é a forma com que tais métodos tratam a entrada e usam expressões regulares que está errada, mas sim o objetivo de cada um deles.

A sugestão então é usar uma expressão válida no [replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-), como `\[.+\]`, que garantirá a substituição de tudo que tenha mais que um caracter e é iniciado por `[` e terminado com `]`, então algo assim:

```
final String[] lines = new String[] {"[ABCDEE+Calibri-11.04]1 ", "[ABCDEE+Georgia,BoldItalic-9.0]Relação de poemas"};
Arrays.stream(lines).forEach(line -> System.out.println(line.replaceAll("\\[.+\\]", "")));
```

Iria imprimir isto:

```
1 
Relação de poemas
```

Answer (score 0):

Observando a assinatura da função [`String.replaceAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)):

```
public String replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)
```

O erro *Illegal character range* é causado porque a função interpreta o primeiro parâmetro como expressão regular [(documentação)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), e os colchetes definem uma classe de caracteres, dentro da classe o hífen define um intervalo de caracteres e o intervalo `i-1` é inválido.

Para resolver é necessário fazer o escape dos colchetes com uma barra invertida (`\`). Outros caracteres com funções especiais, como `.` e `+`, também precisam ser escapados:

```
String line = "[ABCDEE+Calibri-11.04]1 ";
String fontConfiguration = "\[ABCDEE\+Calibri-11\.04\]";
String myText = line.replaceAll(fontConfiguration, "");
```